# LibGDX rendering section of tiled map

Tags: rendering, libgdx, tmx

I am trying to make a tile based game in LibGDX and I have run into some problem. In earlier versions of LibGDX you were able to draw a certain section of a .tmx map instead of a whole and even a section of a layer. Even though , in the nightly builds I cannot find anything about this methods the only thing I have found was drawing of a whole map or one of its layers.

Ideally I would like to draw portion of a map something like draw nao from coords (5,5) to (25,25) . Meaning only the square 22x22 tiles starting from tile in the 5th row/column at position no. 5.

Is it even doable in the newer builds ?

Comment: Take a look in the Tilemaprender class. You define the part you want to draw with an Camera. And you just draw the area of the camera. If you chose just a single layer with the right camerasetting youll just get a part of the tilemap. You can change the zoom for example to get a closer view of the map. You also can change the position of the camera to get a different view

Comment: But when I render map with a camera does it only render the specific part of the map or render it as a whole and then show only the part that fits the camera area ?

Comment: just the part of the map. Its optimized take a look at the render you can see it.